# Fluid is not falling towards gravity

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am animating a cube with a fluid in it falling or'jumping' on two objects and then ending on surface. But my fluid keeps falling towards the side where it was falling on the start. I have turned on animated mesh on fluid[image: this is how it ends]

this is how it ends

Comment: Was your object rotated in object mode? did you apply the rotation? Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data